# Angular 6+ should all @Inputs be observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm a relative Angular (6+) beginner and still finding my way through its wonderful and often confusing landscape. One thing that has recently burnt me is refactoring a few components, which were fetching some data `OnInit()`, to allow them to re-fetch the data whenever any of its `@Input()` properties change instead. That involved making all `@Input()` properties Observable.

I understand that there is the `NgOnChanges()` handler that could be implemented to deal with this, however it looked extremely brittle and hard to maintain and extend due to its loose typing.

Refactoring the existing component was difficult and time consuming due to loads of assumptions made in the component definition, however once I got it working, I realized that it was simpler to use Observables for anything due to the flexibility and extensibility.

What I decided after that exercise, it to make all `@Input()` variables Observable in the future by default as this seems to encourage good practices and makes further extensions/etc much easier.

What are everyone's thoughts on this? Is this a good pattern to get into? Why and why not? Does the slight overhead that I assume is associated with using the Observable pattern outweigh the maintainability/etc?

Comment: If you consumed a third party component that required you to pass in some data (a string, let's say), would you find it convenient to have to wrap this in an observable? Probably not. It seems that you'd end up maintaining two things in your parent component (the string, and the observable).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion having observables for all the inputs just to listen to the changes is an overkill. One way to deal with this `@Input` changes is to have a setter method for your properties.

```
public _prop1: any;

@Input() set prop1(value: any) {

   this._prop1 = value || {};

   this.fetchdata();
}

public _prop2: any;

@Input() set prop2(value: any) {

   this._prop2 = value || {};

   this.fetchdata();
}

public ngOnInit() {

   this.fetchdata();
}

public fetchdata() {

  // Fetch data only when both the properties are available
  if(!this._prop1 || !this._prop2) {
     return;
  }
  // fetch data
}
```

This way you will fetch the data when your properties get changed and also onInit stage.

This is just a one way of designing your component in order to avoid observables for input changes. There are other approaches as well.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern I usually use is that the container components have observable properties and pass it to the child components with the async pipe.

```
data$ = this.dataService.data$;
```

and in the view

```
<child-component [data]="data$ | async"></child-component>
```

Or I wrap it in an ngIf with a view variable

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
    <child-component [data]="data"></child-component>
</ng-container>
```

I cover this pattern in an article on my state mangement library here https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb